# Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /app/assets/images/

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm trying to seed my db with a couple of images for production. Every time I try to seed the database with heroku I het this error:

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /app/assets/images/browse_soup.jpeg
```

Even when trying to add the image in the heroku console I get the same error. Everything worked in development, but now it won't in production. I'm not sure why its saying there is no such file or directory, when I am looking right at it in my rails app.

I'm not quite sure what code to post that will be relevant to help solve this problem, so if anyone has any suggestions or recommendations on code to post, then please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: did you add the image to heroku before doing db:seed?

Comment: I don'y think so. Honestly I have no idea how to do that

Comment: Add it to your git and push the branch to heroku remote.. in other words how are you pushing your code to heroku?

Comment: Do a search in your project for `browse_soup`.

Comment: oo I'm doing a git push heroku master